# How to convert list of generic subtypes to list of specific subtype?

Tags: java, list, generics, wildcard, subtype

Suppose class `B` extends class `A` and we have

```
List<? extends A> list1;
List<B> list2;
```

Is there a way to assign `list1` to `lsit2` without running through all elements?

Comment: Unfortunately, no ;-)

Comment: @Vahan if your question is answered, please mark it answered.

Answer (score 1):

`List<B> list2 = (List<B>)list1`;

You will have to deal with compiler warning and possibly `ClassCastExceptions` when getting Elements from `list2`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, no.

The reason is that the compiler doesn't have any evidence that the runtime types of the `list1` elements will be `B` (or any subtype of `B`). They could be of type `C extends A`, which could lead to `ClassCastException`s at Runtime.

However, you can always traverse through the `list1` and add all the elements to `list2` by doing casts (only if you're confident that the types are compatible, of course). Even though it would work, however, is a sign of a bad design.